# Display port 6080 for ArcGIS 10.0 Server

Tags: arcgis-server, display

I couldn't display port 6080 for ArcGIS 10.0

[image]
[image]

Comment: you must ensure that your firewall allows HTTP communication through this port  https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/ports-used-by-arcgis-server.htm

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 is super-ancient, and HTTPS really ought to be your starting point, so make sure ports 6080 and 6443 are open, then immediately enable HTTPS.

Comment: ArcGIS Server changed so-so-soooo much between 10.0 and 10.1. I _dont think_ that 6080 was a port that 10.0 used. (But that's over 10 years ago, I might not be remembering correctly)

Comment: @KHibma you are correct. I've updated my answer below

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, version 10.0 does not use HTTP port 6080 to communicate. Based on this forum Q&A [arcgis server 10.0 can't log to manager using 6080 port](https://community.esri.com/thread/194359-arcgis-server-100-cant-log-to-manager-using-6080-port)

> At 10.0, you reach Server Manager through ports 80 and 443.  Starting at 10.1, you'll reach Manager through 6080 and 6443.

If that or other ports outline below doesn't work. It may be the case that the OS you are using with it wasn't designed to work on it, or perhaps you may need to more recent ArcGIS Server to use.

ArcGIS Server 10.1 and beyond, I would refer to on ArcGIS's documentation [Ports used by ArcGIS Server](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/ports-used-by-arcgis-server.htm) As the comments mentioned above, you will need to ensure no blocking is happening by a firewall. You may need to install [ArcGIS Web Adaptor](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/about-the-arcgis-web-adaptor.htm) as indicated below.

> ArcGIS Server uses certain ports to communicate with machines on the Internet and intranet. Below is a description of the ports that you may need to allow on your firewall.
>
> HTTP port 6080
> ArcGIS Server initially communicates through port 6080, and you must ensure that your firewall allows HTTP communication through this port. If you don't want users of the server to know about or include port 6080 in their requests, the recommended action is to install ArcGIS Web Adaptor.

Comment: I dont think that this current documentation is accurate for 10.0

Comment: it's for 10.7 is that to new for 10.0? The documentation does go back to 10.3 by click on the drop down version link

Comment: @KHibma you are correct. I've updated my answer above

Comment: Note that Web Adaptor isn't actually required to allow external sites to access your ArcGIS Server on standard HTTP/HTTPS ports (80/443).  You just need to configure a web server with a reverse proxy.  I have configured a reverse proxy in IIS to enable external access to our ArcGIS Server, without Web Adaptor and it works fine.  I would prefer Apache or Nginx, but IIS is what is available by default on Windows Servers, anyhow.